# Is there a function that deletes a cells value if I delete the value of another cell in the same row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently setting up a small inventory tool and since I'm new to vba I got stuck.

So I got a table where you can register all the ingoing and outgoing goods and so far I've included a macro which automatically puts the date into the row if the cells in the ingoing and outgoing columns are changed.

What I want to do now is that if I delete a value in the outgoing/ingoing columns the date will disappear too.

That's my code so far:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range

  On Error GoTo Ende
  Application.EnableEvents = False


  For Each rng In Application.Intersect(Columns("D"), Target).Cells
    If rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then
    rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = Date
    End If
  Next rng

Ende:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I suppose you could check if `Target` is blank, and if so delete the corresponding date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quck and dirty fix - add another for loop that checks if the target cell is empty:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range

  On Error GoTo Ende
  Application.EnableEvents = False


  For Each rng In Application.Intersect(Columns("D"), Target).Cells
    If rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then
    rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = Date
    End If
  Next rng

  For Each rng In Application.Intersect(Columns("D"), Target).Cells
    If rng = "" Then
    rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = ""
    End If
  Next rng

Ende:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Damn, that was easier than I thought! Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!